# Importing a module implemented in ngrx and re-using effect with overriden service

Tags: angular, ngrx, effects, ngrx-effects

I am facing an issue in importing and re-using a module implemented using ngrx.
In simple Angular implementation, below is the use case

```
// Module
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [BaseComponent],
    exports: [
        BaseComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        BaseService
    ]
})
export class BaseModule { }

//component
@Component({
  selector: 'base-comp',
  templateUrl: './base.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./base.component.css']
})
export class BaseComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public service: BaseService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

If i import BaseModule into another module, override service and use 'base-comp' component, i get the OverriddenService instance injected in the BaseComponent

```
// module
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild([{
            path: '',
            component: SecondComponent
        }]),
        BaseModule,
    ],
    declarations: [SecondComponent],
    providers: [
        { provide: BaseService, useClass: OverridenService }
    ]
})
export class SecondModule { }
```

This all works as expected.
Now if i have the module implemented using ngrx and service is injected in constructor in BaseEffect (base-effect.ts) - how to achieve the same result?  If i register a new effect in the SecondModule, there will be two subscriptions to the same action.

```
 @Injectable()
export class BaseEffect {
  constructor(private actions$: Actions,
    private service: BaseService
  ) {
  }

  // Listing
  @Effect()
  listSegments$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.ofType<MyAction>(MY_ACTION)
    .map((action: MyAction) => action.payload)
    .mergeMap((payload: Query) => {
      return this.service.getList(payload).map(response =>
        new ActionComplete(response)
      )
    });
}
```